# How to disable autocorrect in textarea without disabling spellcheck on IE11?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

It seems that if I mark the spellcheck attribute to false, it fixes the auto correct problem but then it does not underline the wrongly spelled word.

```
<textarea id="TextArea1"  spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

I don't want to disable spellcheck, but I don't like its auto-correct feature.
How to create a custom spellcheck attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the JavaScript when HTML isn't enough.

The following code prevents any auto-correction (*specially* built for IE-11):

```
var t = document.querySelector('#t');
var prev = '', len = 0;

t.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  len = t.value.length;
  if(e.keyCode === 32) {
    t.value = prev + ' ';
  }

  prev = t.value;
  console.log(prev);
});
```

```js
var t = document.querySelector('#t');
var prev = '', len = 0;

t.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  len = t.value.length;
  if(e.keyCode === 32)
    t.value = prev + ' ';

  prev = t.value;
});
```

```html
<textarea id='t' spellcheck='true' autocomplete='off'></textarea>
```

Reference: [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp), [`String charAt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp)

Comment: @DeepakMishra Thanks! `e.keyCode === 32` was actually perfect.

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: When the question was originally asked, it didn't specify IE11. This solution apparently does not work on IE11.*

Try the following:

```
<textarea autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
```

Keep in mind that `autocorrect` and `autocapitalize` are not standard attributes and are not supported by all browsers.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Attributes

Comment: not working in IE 11. type onlien and it automatically gets corrected to online.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised... It should work on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on iOS. I don't know about other browsers.

Comment: Try it in IE11, type onlien.

Comment: Why should I try it? I already said that I believe you. If you say it's not working, it's not working. As I said in the answer, it's not supported by all browsers. It works on some, it does not on others.

Comment: for IE11, you will need to ensure the the HTML contains `<!doctype html>` at the top to make it HTML5 compliant @DeepakMishra

Comment: okay, that's because I was testing it in IE (using visual studio).

Comment: @Ahmad yes it's there `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Kresimir IE is a major browser, I know it's not that popular, but still you can't ignore it. I mentioned IE11 on the question, just to provide more information.

Comment: I'm not ignoring it, I simply provided a solution that apparently does not work on IE11, because at the time I wrote my answer, you didn't yet edit your question to specify IE11. I don't know how to solve your problem for IE11.

Comment: @Kresimir no problem, I appreciate and thank for your time.